# Samba: max length of "write list" in smb.conf

Tags: samba, centos-7

I'm trying to reconfigure our samba systems so that the read list is always a group and the write list is a comma separated list of usernames (for various reasons).

I can't find anywhere if there is a maximum length of a samba field. Does anyone know?

I am using CentOS 7.5 and Samba 4.7.1.